# Regex - multiple matches to accept

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to Regex and trying to carry out 3 separate matches on a string, using .php. All 3 must match in order for it to be accepted.

I have a string that will go into a form that specifies the following:

KON-92382

Where KON (Konica) can either be: KON, HEW or CAN
Where '-' is mandatory in this position
Where 5 (strict) digit code must start with 9

So, I need to check the first 3 positions and then TRUE or FALSE
If TRUE, check 4th position and then TRUE or FALSE
Check 5th-9th position that they start with a 9 and then TRUE or FALSE

All 3 checks must result in TRUE, otherwise the check should return FALSE

End users will enter the printer tag into our internal ticketing system and these strings equate to a printer in our assets database.

So far I have tested the following as working, but I need to expand the code so that the '9' can be either 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 as I am planning to use this number to identify the class of printer (ie - 4 will be A3 Colour MFD)

/(KON|HEW|CAN)(-)(9)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/

My 'dirty' fix is as follows:

$format = "/(KON-4)|(KON-9)|(HEW-4)|(HEW-9)|(CAN-4)|(CAN-9)(-)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/";

In this example, i've only specified type 4 or 9 to keep it simple, because the question is more about matching ALL 3 criteria.

Another note, I do not want the 4-9 to be a range (reason being that I want type 5 to fail (ie. KON-51234) as I will be taking all type 5 B/W MFDs out of service pending provider removing from sites and therefore any ticket with this string should fail so that service desk know that this is not an active printer)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You could specify separate allowed numbers `^(?:KON-[46-9]|HEW-[4-9]|CAN-[4-9])\d{4}$` https://regex101.com/r/uYle2A/1

Answer (score 1):

You could specify different allowed numbers for every match:

```
^(?:KON-[46-9]|HEW-[4-9]|CAN-[4-9])\d{4}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `KON-[46-9]|HEW-[4-9]|CAN-[4-9]`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uYle2A/1).

Example for valid matches:

```
$strings = [
    "KON-92382",
    "KON-51234",
    "HEW-71111",
    "CAN-31111",
    "KON-912345"
];

$pattern = "/^(?:KON-[46-9]|HEW-[4-9]|CAN-[4-9])\d{4}$/";

print_r(preg_grep($pattern, $strings));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => KON-92382
    [2] => HEW-71111
)
```